# Improper formatting of Welcome box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

A user from another site (tombull89) wishes to report a formatting problem for non-logged in template. Here is a screenshot. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSdga.png]

He is using Firefox 7.0.1 on Windows 7, but Cerberus reports the same problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in our next daily build.